# When you do Hagba - do you say V'Zos HaTorah?

Tags: minhag, torah-service

If you are the one who is doing Hagba - lifting up the Sefer Torah after Leining - (the Minhag is to point or to bow at the Torah when you say V'Zos HaTorah and it is impossible for the one doing Hagba to point or bow) do you still say V'Zos HaTorah?

Comment: Why do you think you might not?

Comment: The pointing was originally [a Sephardic](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1180/2), not Ashkenazic minhag. I doubt that the recitation is dependent on it.

Comment: I believe @IsaacMoses and Hacham Gabriel are making similar points (no pun intended).  The pointing/bowing is ancillary to the recitation vzos, not part of the main ritual.

Comment: I understand the points made, however the fact that there are those who point or bow made me wonder.

Comment: you don't need to point or bow when you say V'Zos HaTorah

Answer (score 7):

Just found in [Sefer Pirchei Aharon](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39336&pgnum=43) that the original Minhag was that the one who did Hagba said "V'zos HaTorah Asher Som Moshe Lifnei Bnei Yisroel" and the rest of the Shul would answer "Al Pi Hashem B'Yad Moshe"

וכנראה היה המנהג הקדמון שהמגביה
 היה אומר ,וזאת התורה אשר שם משה
 לפני בני ישראל, והעם עונין ,על פי
 ה׳ ביד משה

Based on this I would say that the one who does Hagba should say V'Zos HaTorah.