# In the phrase זכר למעשה בראשית in Kiddush, is the word זכר an adjective?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, kiddush, vowels-nekudot

Usually, a word that has a segol such as "zecher" gets a tzerei when it becomes an adjective. Example - "mateh" becomes "matei" when used as an adjective as in "matei Levi".

Q - in the phrase זכר למעשה בראשית is the word זכר  considered an adjective? On the one hand, I would say, yes by the fact that it has a tzerei. However, I am not sure because the next word starts with ל (meaning "to" or "for"), which is a preposition.

Comment: In Mattei it's the last syllable that is a Tzere whereas in Zecher it's the first. Also, Mattei is not an adjective, but rather the genitive case of the noun IINM.

Comment: _Mate_ with a _tzere_ is a noun in construct state.

Comment: @msh210 ["Note that this differs from the genitive case of European languages in that it is the head (modified) noun rather than the dependent (modifying) noun which is marked."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construct_state) Touché. I had heard both terms and didn't appreciate the difference.

Comment: "a word that has a segol such as 'zecher'" TTBOMK there is no such word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a noun. (As far as I know, *zecher* is always a noun.) Many a noun has a *tzere*, such as סֵפֶר and חֵלֶק. See Gesenius, [84<sup>a</sup>](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius'_Hebrew_Grammar/84a)a and [93](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius'_Hebrew_Grammar/93).