# Must one follow Minhagim he reads in books?

Tags: minhag, jewish-books, halacha-theory, mesorah-tradition

If an Ashkenazi reads of a minhag, for example in Mishna Brura which it says Ashkenazim follow (the Rema), must he follow it? Or is it only what a father teaches his children?

Comment: Orion, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for posting this fundamental question! I hope it gets great answers and that you  look around and find other material of interest, perhaps starting with other questions in the [tag:mesorah-tradition] tag.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37751/adopting-minhagim-not-from-your-mesorah?rq=1

Comment: I don't understand why you might think he must follow it by virtue of his reading it. Please edit to add some motivation to your question

Comment: " Or is it only what your father teaches you?" And, what if your father teaches you incorrectly or insufficiently?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17459/759

Comment: "Or is it only what a father teaches his children?" you may want to look up the concept of 'minhag hamokom'