# Pointing the pinky at the torah

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, torah-service, hands-fingers

By *Hagbahos HaTorah* people point at the *Torah* with the pinky of their right hand. I have seen others point with the pinky of both hands. Someone told me this is brought down in the Me’am Lo’ez. Where does the Me’am Lo’ez mention this *minhag*?

Answer (score 3):

As [noted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2503/170) by [Ishyehudi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/148/ishyehudi):

> It is from the Meam Loez (Ki Savo, 27:26)

Comment: great article here, BTW: http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/torah-on-display.html