# Is showing excessive honor to Gedolim idolatry?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rabbis, avodah-zarah, kavod

At what point is the *kavod* shown toward the Gedolim considered idolatry?

Terms like 'Gadolatry' are sometimes used as if to indicate that too much respect is being shown for certain rabbis to the point that it is akin to a form of idolatry - or perhaps even actual idolatry.

When is it called *kavod haTorah* and at what point should this - at times excessive -admiration be considered idolatry (if at all)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20882/discussion-on-question-by-el-shteiger-is-showing-excessive-honor-to-gedolim-idol).

Comment: not idolatry but perhaps in some cases a bit absurd. I remember being told when I was younger it was a practice in some yeshivas then young men should shave and only the rosh kollel and head rabbis should have beards b/c kavod harav. this struck me as really absurd considering it is a mitzvah not to shave and has always been a part of the quintessential appearance of a Jewish man

Answer (score 6):

Well, we learn (פסחים כב:)  that we have to be in awe of Talmidei Chachomim from an extra word in the Pasuk that commands us to be in awe of Hashem - ***את** ה' א-לקיך  תִּירָא* לְרַבּוֹת תַּלְמִידֵי חֲכָמִים. ‏

The laws concerning honouring and respecting a Talmid Chacham are very severe - as documented in [שלחן ערוך - יורה דעה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_34.html). Here's some samples:

[סימן רמב - שלא להורות בפני הרב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_34.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2)

> **א** חַיָּב אָדָם בִּכְבוֹד רַבּוֹ וְיִרְאָתוֹ יוֹתֵר מִבְּשֶׁל אָבִיו ‏
>
> **ב** כָּל הַחוֹלֵק עַל רַבּוֹ, כְּחוֹלֵק עַל הַשְּׁכִינָה. וְכָל הָעוֹשֶׂה מְרִיבָה עִם רַבּוֹ, כְּעוֹשֶׂה עִם הַשְּׁכִינָה. וְכָל הַמִּתְרַעֵם עָלָיו, כְּאִלּוּ מִתְרַעֵם עַל הַשְּׁכִינָה. וְכָל הַמְהַרְהֵר אַחַר רַבּוֹ, כִּמְהַרְהֵר אַחַר הַשְּׁכִינָה.‏
>
> **טז** לֹא יִתֵּן שָׁלוֹם לְרַבּוֹ וְלֹא יַחֲזִיר לוֹ שָׁלוֹם, כְּדֶרֶךְ שְׁאָר הָעָם, אֶלָּא שׁוֹחֶה לְפָנָיו וְאוֹמֵר לוֹ בְּיִרְאָה וּבְכָבוֹד: (שָׁלוֹם עָלֶיךָ רַבִּי, וְאִם נָתַן לוֹ רַבּוֹ שָׁלוֹם, אוֹמֵר לוֹ) שָׁלוֹם עָלֶיךָ מוֹרִי וְרַבִּי. וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּאֵין לְתַלְמִיד לִשְׁאֹל בִּשְׁלוֹם רַבּוֹ כְּלָל, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: רָאוּנִי נְעָרִים וְנֶחְבָּאוּ (אִיּוֹב כח, ט) ... ‏
>
> **יט** כָּל מְלָאכוֹת שֶׁהָעֶבֶד עוֹשֶׂה לְרַבּוֹ תַּלְמִיד עוֹשֶׂה לְרַבּוֹ....‏

However, all the above is only obligatory for one's רַבּוֹ מֻבְהָק - but for a *regular* Talmid Chacham, one does not have to do all the above. But nowhere does it say that one may not.

> **ל** כָּל אֵלּוּ הַדְּבָרִים שֶׁאָמַרְנוּ שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לְכַבֵּד בָּהֶם אֶת רַבּוֹ, לֹא אָמְרוּ אֶלָּא בְּרַבּוֹ מֻבְהָק דְּהַיְנוּ שֶׁרֹב חָכְמָתוֹ מִמֶּנּוּ; אִם מִקְרָא מִקְרָא, אִם מִשְׁנָה, מִשְׁנָה; אִם גְּמָרָא, גְּמָרָא. *הגה: וּבְיָמִים אֵלּוּ עִקַּר הָרַבָּנוּת אֵינוֹ תָּלוּי בְּמִי שֶׁלִּמְּדוֹ הַפִּלְפּוּל וְחִלּוּקִים שֶׁנּוֹהֲגִים בָּהֶם בַּזְּמַן הַזֶּה, רַק בְּמִי שֶׁלִּמְּדוֹ פְּשַׁט הַהֲלָכָה וְהָעִיּוּן וְהֶעֱמִידוֹ עַל הָאֱמֶת וְהַיֹּשֶׁר. (מהרי''ק שֹׁרֶשׁ קס''ט)* . אֲבָל **אִם לֹא לָמַד רֹב חָכְמָתוֹ מִמֶּנּוּ, אֵינוֹ חַיָּב לְכַבְּדוֹ בְּכָל אֵלּוּ הַדְּבָרִים**, אֲבָל עוֹמֵד מִלְּפָנָיו מִשֶּׁיַּגִּיעַ לְאַרְבַּע אַמּוֹתָיו וְקוֹרֵעַ עָלָיו, כְּשֵׁם שֶׁהוּא קוֹרֵעַ עַל כָּל הַמֵּתִים שֶׁהוּא מִתְאַבֵּל עֲלֵיהֶם. אֲפִלּוּ לֹא לָמַד מִמֶּנּוּ אֶלָּא דָּבָר אֶחָד, בֵּין קָטָן בֵּין גָּדוֹל, עוֹמֵד מִלְּפָנָיו וְקוֹרֵעַ עָלָיו .‏

Note that it says אִם לֹא לָמַד רֹב חָכְמָתוֹ מִמֶּנּוּ, אֵינוֹ חַיָּב לְכַבְּדוֹ בְּכָל אֵלּוּ הַדְּבָרִים, but it doesn't say not to. (One could have thought that it may diminish from the respect one gives one's own רַבּוֹ מֻבְהָק, but it seems that this is not so.)

Answer (score 4):

Just to give some perspective. This question [Why isn't it considered idol worship to give respect to the torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50296/why-isnt-it-considered-idol-worship-to-give-respect-to-the-torah)
was met with reactions deeming it practically ridiculous to even ask such a thing.

Now let's see what Rava says in Makkos 22b 'what fools all these other people are! Who stand up for a Seffer Torah, but don't stand up before a great Rabbi!' 
See the Maharsha there who explains this comment is specifically for the unlearned who don't appreciate and respect Talmidei Chachamim, so that this comment won't contradict the gemara in Kidushin 33b.

In any event, let us not confuse RESPECTING the Rabbis, which is a requirement, with feeling beholden to their opinions in mundane matters.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248140/266359

Comment: No problem. Seems you'll need to either add a picture yourself, or [add an email to your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248141/266359). Good luck!