# Showing respect and love for someone or things without worship but with the knowledge it's a deity or considered/treated as one in the eyes of others

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, love

Bowing is considered as a way to show respect, that's why one could bow to a king (Melachim 1:1:23) or why the brothers of Yosef bowed down to him (Bereshit 42:6).

We dance with the Torah on Simchat Torah as a way to show our love.

But these two examples aren't considered as worship, giving respect isn't idol worship, showing love neither, worship an idol/deity is what's considered idol worship. So showing respect to the Torah isn't considered idol worship for example (as asked in this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50296/why-isnt-it-considered-idol-worship-to-give-respect-to-the-torah)).

But does this mean that showing respect or love for a human who's considered to be a deity is allowed? Or show love for a satue (because I fancy the looks of it) is assur? *Is it permissable to show love, respect etc. in a similar fashion to someone or something which is considered to be an idol/deity if one doesn't worship this idol/deity?* (although one knows it's considered to be an idol/deity by others or could be considered as one).